# Maven: The command 'mvn install' related issue

Tags: maven

I have found this very fascinating that 'mvn install' sometimes produces a .class file in the target directory and sometimes it doesn't. Can anyone tell me why is it so? How can I make sure I get the directory every single time?

It's a simple maven module which is added as part of a parent folder. When I execute 'mvn install' on this module, I get a target/test-classes folder but no target/classes folder. This happens on some occasions..
Let me break it up even more...

I create a module which initially has src/test/java and src/test/resources. So I add a source folder called src/main/java and src/main/resources. Now I install the module and I get to see the test-classes folder inside target and no classes folder.
Hope you got it.

Comment: Please provide more details. What is your project structure, what is the class file that you see etc.

Comment: Nope, we didn't got it :-) What is the output of the command? Have you encounter any errors/warnings? Can you pastebin the POM definitions and the output of the `tree` command in the parent folder? I seriously suggest you to read the official [tutorial on multi-module projects](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html), I believe it is a simple configuration issue.

Comment: I think it's because of pom.xml package tag. If you want a jar file, you need to add jar packaging to you pom.xml. Then run 'maven package install'.